# Java : Replacing String Words

Tags: java

I have a String as "**ISTERC Mini BAT**"

The Problem is that the Word Mini May come in Case sensitive Letters (Mini Or MINI )

The requirement is that , i need to remove the word **Mini/MINI** from the String and it should look like "**ISTERC BAT**" 
(Also removed a extra space before Mini)

I have tried this way

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String Symbol = "ISTERC Mini BAT";

        if (Symbol.contains("Mini") || Symbol.contains("MINI")) {
            Symbol = Symbol.replace(" Mini", "");
        }

        System.out.println(Symbol);

    }

}
```

The question is should i write an another `if condition`  to handle if contains ("MINI")

Tried this way after responses

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String Symbol = "ISTERC Mini BAT";

        if (Symbol.contains("(?i)mini")) {

            Symbol = Symbol.replaceAll(" (?i)mini", "");
        }

        System.out.println(Symbol);

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure Mini and MINI are the only allowed forms? Are you sure that it's always surrounded by spaces? Are you sure it appears only once? Your (partially correct) implementation implies that you assume all the above.

Comment: Why are you checking with contains method..The replace method will only replace if the given word is present(contained within the String)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

`Symbol = Symbol.replaceAll("(?i) Mini", "");`

`(?i)` would make replaceAll method to ignore character case sensitivity.

It should work for MINI, MiNi and any other possibility.

**EDIT#1:** 
`System.out.println(Symbol.contains("(?i) Mini", ""));` will result in Boolean response `false` as it does not take regex. It will treat `(?i) Mini` as a String itself.

Comment: This looks good , my another question is , can i use that with Contains also ??

Comment: No,  `String.contains` method does not take regex as it's Parameter. Maybe you would like to implement it with `Pattern` and `Matcher`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `String#replaceAll` and pass regex `(?i)word` (?i) turns on case insensitivity

```
Symbol = Symbol.replaceAll("(?i)mini\\s+", "");
```

Comment: where `(?i)` means case insenstive.

Comment: may be with removal of trailing space char `Symbol.replaceAll("(?i)mini\\s+", "")`

Comment: yep, OP, " (Also removed a extra space before Mini)". ha! it says before.

Comment: Thats right even it could be after also. I'll update my answer. And Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String Symbol = "ISTERC MINI BAT";
        Symbol = Symbol.replaceAll("( mini| MINI)","");  
        System.out.println(Symbol);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("mini", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
System.out.println(pattern.matcher(symbol).replaceAll(""));
```